# Determine what kind of object is created within a java method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extend

I have Java super class named **"Shapes"** and 2 sub class named **"triangle"** and **"circle"**.

I have to create a method in **Shapes** that calculates the area of the object (triangle or circle) created such as this:

**public double areaOfShape(double something)**

I'm not sure what the parameter will be (so I put something...).
Because the formula will differ depending on what kind of object you will create; if it's a rectangle, you will need the length and width. If it's a circle, you will need the radius, so I'm not sure how to continue from there because I'm not sure if I need an "if statement" to determine what kind of object I created?

Comment: Just put the calculateArea method inside each of the subclasses. Or, an if statement works too.

Comment: This assignment is about inheritance I guess, so you have to use it ;)

Comment: NB: the plurality of your class names is confusing: `Shapes` is plural, `triangle` and `circle` are singular.

Comment: I don't know why you need this 'something' parameter.  For me, this is an abstract function withouth parameters, and returning double:  public abstract double areaOfShape().

Answer (score 5):

You need to write Shape class with abstract `calculateArea()` method as Shape won't have any implementation about how to calculate an area. You can then extend Shape class with Triangle and Circle classes and override `calculateArea()` method, as shown below:

```
abstract class Shape{
    public abstract double calculateArea();
}

class Triangle extends Shape{
    @Override
    public double calculateArea(){
        //Triangle implementation
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape{
    @Override
    public double calculateArea(){
        //Circle implementation
    }
}
```

Once this is done, you can instantiate Shape reference with any of the implementation classes and call `calculateArea()` e.g.:

```
Shape s = new Triangle();
s.calculateArea();
```